# How does Ionic add classes to the <body> tag?

Tags: ios, css, cordova, statusbar, ionic-framework

I just realized that on iOS 7 (running app from Xcode into device), Ionic add some classes to the `<body>` tag, as one can see on [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/eculosg6n9lwbdi/Screenshot%202014-06-06%2015.45.18.png) screenshot.

In this case it adds `.platform-ios7.platform-cordova:not(.fullscreen) .bar-header:not(.bar-subheader)`  which seems to be what's responsible for adding that extra space on top of the header bar to accommodate the iOS 7 Status Bar.

I wonder- how is it done?

Because I followed another sample tutorial ([Tabs App](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-tabs)), on which that doesn't happen and the iOS Status bar overlaps the header.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the iOS Status Bar issue by setting `<script src="cordova.js"></script>` to be the last script to load.

But to answer the specific question of this thread:

> Ionic check what device your on by using cordova's device plugin. From
>   there, they add classes to the body to apply device specific classes
>   and styling.

Source [here](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/how-does-ionic-adds-classes-to-the-body-tag/5310/2).